# Cálculo de linhas e colunas JavaScript para PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Preciso entender esse trecho de código js que é responsável por fazer o cálculo do posicionamento das linhas e colunas, de uma table html, para PDF.

```
$(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(index,data) {
      rowCalc = index+1;                                            
      if (rowCalc % 35 == 0){
            doc.addPage();
            page++;
            startRowPosition=startRowPosition+10;

      }
      rowPosition=(startRowPosition + (rowCalc * 10)) - ((page -1) * 280);

      $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){  
                if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                        var colPosition = startColPosition+ (index * 50);                                   
                        doc.text(colPosition,rowPosition, parseString($(this)));
                }
            }
    }); 
});
```

O maior enigma está em:

> function(index,data)

Não consigo entender o que essa função representa e quais e o que são os valores dos parâmetros index e data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, tudo bem?

Então, essa parte do código em especial representa a incialização de um forEach do Jquery.

```
each(function(index,data) {}
```

Ou seja, cada elemento do array  `$(this).filter(':visible').find('td')` será iterado pelo for each, o parametro **index** é referente a um contador do elemento que está sendo iterado. Já o **data** é o valor que está sendo iterado.

Exemplo:

```
const test = ['a','b','c']
$test.each(function(index, data){
  console.log(index, data) //vai printar na primeira iteracao (0, a)
  console.log(index, data) //vai printar na segunda iteracao (1, b)
  console.log(index, data) //vai printar na terceira iteracao (2, c)
}
```

Aqui o link da documentação do Jquery com mais exemploes de utilização do **$each**:
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: no caso teria somente um console.log(index, data) que iria iterar 3 vezes né?

Comment: Exatamente! O console.log vai ser somente um, coloquei os três para mostrar todas iterações que acontecerão.

Comment: show! muito obrigado